# mysql update issues where id in

Tags: mysql

a have a new issues today..

Don't know why it doesn't works but I'm trying to update table column using a where id in().
I got this error:

```
You can't specify target table 'membre_non_filtrer' for update in FROM clause
```

this is the function:

```
UPDATE membre_non_filtrer 
SET chef=1 where id IN(
        SELECT tt.id FROM membre_non_filtrer tt INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT famid, MAX(age) AS maxAge 
        FROM membre_non_filtrer GROUP BY famid)
        groupedtt ON tt.famid = groupedtt.famid 
        AND tt.age = groupedtt.maxAge ORDER BY `tt`.`famid` ASC)
```

Just to tell you that  the SELECT works and return a good value.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you run in mysql workbench and see which line it is reporting the error on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick trick would be alias your subquery like `IN(SELECT t.id FROM (subquery) t )`

```
UPDATE membre_non_filtrer 
SET chef=1 where id IN(
SELECT t.id FROM       
 SELECT tt.id FROM membre_non_filtrer tt INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT famid, MAX(age) AS maxAge 
        FROM membre_non_filtrer GROUP BY famid)
        groupedtt ON tt.famid = groupedtt.famid 
        AND tt.age = groupedtt.maxAge ORDER BY `tt`.`famid` ASC
) t
)
```

Or you can use join

```
UPDATE 
  membre_non_filtrer tt 
  INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      famid,
      MAX(age) AS maxAge 
    FROM
      membre_non_filtrer 
    GROUP BY famid) groupedtt 
    ON tt.famid = groupedtt.famid 
    AND tt.age = groupedtt.maxAge
 SET tt.chef = 1
```